# a problem with normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have some problems with this

The annual rainfall (in inches) in a certain region is
normally distributed with μ = 40 and σ = 4. What
is the probability that, starting with this year, it will
take over 10 years before a year occurs having a
rainfall of over 50 inches? What assumptions are
you making?

Let X be a  normal random variable with μ = 40 and σ = 4 that represents the annual rainfall.
$$P(X>= 50)=P((X-\mu )/\sigma  \ge (50-10)/4 =2,5)=1-\Phi (2,5)=0.9938$$

Let Y be a geometric random variable with parameter $$p=0,9938$$
The probability that it will take over 10 years before a year occurs having a
rainfall of over 50 inches would be  $$P(Y=11)=0,9938^{10}*(1-0,9938)$$ because at the eleventh year we will have surely a rainfall of over 50 inches. But the solution on the book is $$0,9938^{10}$$ only.

Why?

I'm assuming that each event is independent from the others.

Comment: "Over 10 years before it rains" is the event $Y \geq 11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says *over* ten years, not exactly ten years. So that's equivalent to the first 10 years having less than 50 inches.

Comment: And if we had to find probability that in the 11th year we will have a rainfall of 50 inches, will it be $0.993810^{10} \cdot (1-0.993810)^1$?